# Copy MQ Messages from one Queue to another

Tags: ibm-mq

**Question**:

*Is it possible to copy MQ Messages from one Queue Manager/Queue to a different Queue Manager/Queue?*

**Scenario**:

I have a "PROD" Queue Manager and when it receives a Message on it's Queues I would like to "copy" the Message to a queue on a "TEST" Queue Manager.

**Requirements**

- The original message must be left on the PROD queue to be processed as normal.
- This must be an automated process (lots of messages during a day). I could not intervene on a Message by Message basis.
- If at all possible I would like this to be implemented by some native MQ functionality rather than an ad hoc program/script.
- The copying must be as near to real time as possible
- Must work with MQ version is 7.0.2.1(!). This cannot be changed.
- Must run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga). Again, can't be changed.

I'm no MQ expert so use small words please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21574670) pointed out by gouda is that MQ will modify/changed the MsgId and CorrelId of each message replicated.

If the MsgId and/or CorrelId fields are important then the only other option is an MQ API Exit that replicates the message.  You may need a commercial product like [MQ Message Replication](http://capitalware.com/mqmr_overview.html).

The next question is how are you going to move the message from a PROD queue to a TEST queue?  You definitely do NOT want to create channels between a PROD queue manager and a TEST queue manager.

There are lots of tools that can off offload PROD messages to a file then you can move the file to your TEST environment and then load the messages into a TEST queue.  Here is a list of [MQ tools](http://capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html#msgedit) that can do it.  The 2 tools you should try out are: MQ Batch Toolkit and QLoad.

Personally, I would create a schedule task (CRONTAB) to be run every night at midnight to off the messages and I would make the filename include the date and time.  The last steps of the script would be to zip/compress the file and delete the original file (because the data you offload could be massive).

Hence, any time you want a particular day's PROD messages, just copy the file to your TEST server and unzip/uncompress it and load it into the queue.

Comment: you said "You definitely do NOT want to create channels between a PROD queue manager and a TEST queue manager.". Is this for an "MQ reason" or for good practice i.e. keep PROD data siloed? thanks

Comment: Best Practices & it will keep simple accidents from happening.  Pandora's box - you just don't want to open it because bad things may/will happen.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is mqadmin staff and this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21574670)

Comment: Thanks I'll review this today